# Recyclerview only refresh the items showed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have an adapter with some actions that refresh the ui of the item. My problem is that the refresh has a logic that change every single item, but It's changing only the items that appears on the screen, If I scrolldown the recycler the items that were not in the screen are not updated.

```
    public class RowOperativaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RowOperativaAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private int id;
    private OperateModel operateModel;
    private OperateModel operateFavoriteModel;
    private int fragmentPositionNumber;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position, int fragmentPosition);
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public RowOperativaAdapter(Context context, int id, OperateModel operateModel, int fragmentPositionNumber) {
        this.context = context;
        this.id = id;
        this.fragmentPositionNumber = fragmentPositionNumber;
        this.operateModel = operateModel;
    }

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    //    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public RelativeLayout lay_icon;
        public ImageView img_option;
        public ImageView optionAddFavorites;
        public ImageView optionDelFavorites;
        public BMLTextView optionText;
        public View layout;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            layout = v;
            lay_icon = (RelativeLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.lay_icon);
            img_option = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.img_option);
            optionDelFavorites = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.iv_del_favorites);
            optionAddFavorites = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.iv_add_favorites);
            optionText = (BMLTextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.txt_option_description);

            lay_icon.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null){
                mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition(), fragmentPositionNumber);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean addItem(int positionFragment, OperativeItemModel itemModel) {

        boolean done = false;

        //OperativeItemModel operativeClicked = ((RowOperativaAdapter)context.operateOptionHelper.getListOperateFragments().get(fragmentPosition).getRvSectionOperations().getAdapter()).getItem(position);


        if (getFavoritesOperative() == null) {
            List<OperativeItemModel> favoritesNull = new ArrayList<OperativeItemModel>();
            favoritesNull.add(itemModel);
            OperateModel operateModel = new OperateModel(getParentContext().getResources().getString(R.string.operate_favorites), favoritesNull, false, true);
            setFavoriteOperative(operateModel);
            getParentContext().getOperateOptionHelper().getListOperateFragments().get(0).setOperateModel(getFavoritesOperative());
            getParentContext().getOperateOptionHelper().getListOperateFragments().get(0).getSectionItemHelper().reSetUpFavoriteRV(getFavoritesOperative());
            getParentContext().getOperateOptionHelper().getListOperateFragments().get(0).getRvSectionOperations().getAdapter().notifyItemInserted(0);
            done = true;
        } else if (getFavoritesOperative() != null && getFavoritesOperative().getOperatives() == null) {
            List<OperativeItemModel> operativesNull = new ArrayList<OperativeItemModel>();
            operativesNull.add(itemModel);
            getFavoritesOperative().setOperatives(new ArrayList<OperativeItemModel>());
            getFavoritesOperative().setOperatives(operativesNull);
            getParentContext().getOperateOptionHelper().getListOperateFragments().get(0).setOperateModel(getFavoritesOperative());
            getParentContext().getOperateOptionHelper().getListOperateFragments().get(0).getSectionItemHelper().reSetUpFavoriteRV(getFavoritesOperative());
            getParentContext().getOperateOptionHelper().getListOperateFragments().get(0).getRvSectionOperations().getAdapter().notifyItemInserted(0);
            done = true;
        } else if (getFavoritesOperative() != null && getFavoritesOperative().getOperatives() != null) {
            if (!getFavoritesOperative().getOperatives().contains(itemModel)) {
                List<OperativeItemModel> operativeContains = getFavoritesOperative().getOperatives();
                operativeContains.add(itemModel);
                getFavoritesOperative().setOperatives(new ArrayList<OperativeItemModel>());
                getFavoritesOperative().setOperatives(operativeContains);

                getParentContext().getOperateOptionHelper().getListOperateFragments().get(0).setOperateModel(getFavoritesOperative());
                getParentContext().getOperateOptionHelper().getListOperateFragments().get(0).getSectionItemHelper().reSetUpFavoriteRV(getFavoritesOperative());
                getParentContext().getOperateOptionHelper().getListOperateFragments().get(0).getRvSectionOperations().getAdapter().notifyItemInserted(operativeContains.size()-1);
                done = true;
            }
        }
        getParentContext().getOperateOptionHelper().getListOperateFragments().get(0).getRvSectionOperations().getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

        return done;
    }

    public boolean delItem(int positionFragment, OperativeItemModel itemModel) {

        boolean done = false;

        if (getFavoritesOperative() != null && getFavoritesOperative().getOperatives() != null) {
            if (getFavoritesOperative().getOperatives().contains(itemModel)) {    // -1 means doesn't contains the model
                int index = getParentContext().getOperateOptionHelper().getListOperateFragments().get(0).getOperateModel().getOperatives().indexOf(itemModel);
                getFavoritesOperative().getOperatives().remove(itemModel);
                done = getParentContext().getOperateOptionHelper().getListOperateFragments().get(0).getOperateModel().getOperatives().remove(itemModel);
                getParentContext().getOperateOptionHelper().getListOperateFragments().get(0).getRvSectionOperations().getAdapter().notifyItemRemoved(index);
                if(getFavoritesOperative() != null && getFavoritesOperative().getOperatives() != null){
                    if(getFavoritesOperative().getOperatives().size() == 0){
                        getParentContext().getOperateOptionHelper().getListOperateFragments().get(0).getSectionItemHelper().setUpFavoritesOperationsRV();
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        getParentContext().getOperateOptionHelper().getListOperateFragments().get(0).getRvSectionOperations().getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

        return done;

    }

    public int position(OperativeItemModel item) {
        return getFavoritesOperative().getOperatives().indexOf(item);    // -1 if this list does not contain the element
    }

    public int nextPositionAvailable() {
        return operateModel.getOperatives().size();
    }

    public OperativeItemModel getItem(int position) {
        return operateModel.getOperatives().get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public int positionInFavorite(OperativeItemModel item){

        return operateModel.getOperatives().indexOf(item);

    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public RowOperativaAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_operative_item, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        final OperativeItemModel operative = operateModel.getOperatives().get(position);

        if (getFragmentPositionNumber() == 0) {
            if (getParentContext().isEditingFavorites()) {
                if (getFavoritesOperative() != null && getFavoritesOperative().getOperatives() != null) {
                    if (getFavoritesOperative().getOperatives().contains(operative)) {
                        drawOperativeIcon(holder, operative, false, true);
                    } else {
                        drawOperativeIcon(holder, operative, null, true);
                    }
                } else {
                    drawOperativeIcon(holder, operative, null, true);
                }
            } else {
                drawOperativeIcon(holder, operative, null, true);
            }
        } else {
            if (getParentContext().isEditingFavorites()) {
                if (getFavoritesOperative() != null && getFavoritesOperative().getOperatives() != null) {
                    if (getFavoritesOperative().getOperatives().contains(operative)) {
                        drawOperativeIcon(holder, operative, false, false);
                    } else {
                        drawOperativeIcon(holder, operative, true, false);
                    }
                } else {
                    drawOperativeIcon(holder, operative, true, false);
                }
            } else {
                drawOperativeIcon(holder, operative, null, false);
            }
        }

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return operateModel.getOperatives().size();
    }

    public RowOperativaAdapter getAdapterFromFragment(int fragmentPositionNumber) {
        return this;
    }

    public int getFragmentPositionNumber() {
        return this.fragmentPositionNumber;
    }

    public ClientActivity getParentContext() {
        return (ClientActivity) context;
    }

    public OperateModel getFavoritesOperative() {
        return getParentContext().getGlobalPositionApiController().getFavoritesSection();
    }

    public void setFavoriteOperative(OperateModel favoriteOperative) {
        getParentContext().getGlobalPositionApiController().setFavoritesSection(favoriteOperative);
    }

    public void drawOperativeIcon(ViewHolder holder, OperativeItemModel operative, @Nullable Boolean addDelIndicator, Boolean favorite) {
        if (addDelIndicator == null) {
            holder.optionDelFavorites.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.optionAddFavorites.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else if (addDelIndicator) {
            holder.optionDelFavorites.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.optionAddFavorites.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (!addDelIndicator) {
            holder.optionDelFavorites.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.optionAddFavorites.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        holder.img_option.setImageDrawable(CommonUtils.getDrawableByName(holder.img_option.getContext(), operative.getIcon(), favorite, holder.img_option.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.section_operation_mock)));
        holder.optionText.setText(operative.getName());
        holder.optionText.setSelected(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you indicate where is this logic as the code you pasted is rather large and takes some time to read through it. Are you calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` anywhere?

Comment: yeah, when I add or remove items